# android listview order changed when called notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

all.
   when I use notifyDataSetChanged(), the listview display order will be change .

like this

- 3
- 2
- 1

  when current activy was created. but when I change the data. it will be
- 1
- 2
- 3

I don't want the order changed and i dont understand why its happening.

This is a piece of code from my adapter class

```
    public static class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private String[] mData;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

// I called this method  to change data
        public void setEditText(int position, final String item) {
            mData[position] = item;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



}
```

I change data at some dialog like this

```
       builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ct);
                            builder.setTitle(R.string.pickStatus)
                                    .setView(edBuffer)
                                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    canPop = true;
                                                    final String tmp = edBuffer.getText().toString();
                                                    KbonezLog.e(String.format( "set into key %d", key)); 
//use mData key to set value
setEditText(key, tmp);
dialog.dismiss();
}})
```

Comment: Looks okay so far. Let's see your implementation of Adapter.getView().

Comment: Post a snippet of code creating an adapter and getView() method from adapter. You could also add a snippet how you obtain a "key" variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the full source code for your adapter, but this sounds like an issue in your implementation of getView(). Every time getView() is invoked you *must* rebind all the data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that in setEditText you are actually changing the list contents, so that might be a good place to start looking for issues.

Answer (score 0):

i think instead of using **private String[] mData;**, You should use following,

```
private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
mData.add(item);
```

In my case, it works and does not change data, i hope you will solve your problem from this.

Comment: thanks for your reply,I tried it yesterday and there is some problem about data type. I will try it later. when I success, I will post here.